# iptables with regex url matching

Tags: regex, iptables

What I need to achieve
   I need count how many users open correct websites and sub websites
    e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com'
         'https://stackoverflow.com/questions'

What I have 
   router set on Centos 7
   Iptables
   https://github.com/xnsystems/kpcre/wiki/iptables-string-regex

I can't use squid.
   this count system can't change IP headers (src and dst IP address)
   that is why I need count use iptables with log option
   or maybe there is software which will count urls without any packet modification

Problem
   I can't find a way in which I will see how many IP adress (how many users) hit correct url

My iptables row looks like this and doesn't work
   I mean match all urls (with all sub urls) not only http://stackoverflow.com

> `sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "^http://stackoverflow.com$" --algo regex -j ACCEPT`

Please help me with this case.

UPDATE:
Below three examples please try make them works

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string stackoverflow.com --algo regex -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string stackoverflow.com/documentation --algo regex -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string stackoverflow.com/questions'; --algo regex -j ACCEPT
```

As you see I used --algo regex.
If you know another solution without it please suggest.

Comment: I know nothing about iptables. But your regex might be improved by quoting the special characters `/` and `.`. Meaning you shouold use `\/\/` and `\.` instead.

Comment: To make it match other urls, can you tell me which flavor of regex (sed, grep, perl) your program uses? For perl flavor this might help: `^http:\/\/\w+(\.\w+)+$`

Comment: I'm using this program. That is all I know. But how it works I don't know.
- https://github.com/xnsystems/kpcre/wiki/iptables-string-regex

Answer (score 0):

I checked the specification link, it is not very complete (e.g. `\b`seems know, but is not explained), but I think the regex you need is:

```
^(http:\/\/){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){0,}$
```

UPDATE: Allow `http://`prefix and `/documentation` suffix.

Please try.
The use of capture groups `()` is not specified, but that usually works.
If you give examples which match and should not or do not match and should, I will adapt this answer.
The easiest adaptation is to insert more characters (to be allowed for the URL) between the `[a-zA-Z0-9_`and the `-]`, in two places.

Comment: Below three examples please try make them works ### sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string stackoverflow.com --algo regex -j ACCEPT ### ### sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string stackoverflow.com/documentation --algo regex -j ACCEPT ### ### sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string stackoverflow.com/questions'; --algo regex -j ACCEPT ### As you see I used --algo regex. If you know another solution without it please suggest.

Comment: @user7796341 Sorry. I don't do iptables. If you can extract the regex problem, I will try to help. You might want to update your question with the results of the experiments you made, e.g. update the regex if my comment improved something.

Comment: Understand.
Please tell me how use your regex. I mean how to match exact this ### http://stackoverflow.com ### and this ### stackoverflow.com/documentation ###

Comment: The regex already does match "http://stackoverflow.com". I tested with egrep. Do you need it to match without "http://", too? Then try `^(http:\/\/){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$`. Or is there another problem? How to use the regex is an iptables question I cannot answer.

Comment: Sorry, the markdown has hidden the `http://` in the url  I stated to work. I tested `http://stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: In order to also optionally match a suffix "/doc" or "/doc/something", use this regex `^(http:\/\/){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){0,}$`.

Comment: Hmm
I don't understand how your answer will match my websites?

http://stackoverflow.com
http://stackoverflow.com/documentation

Comment: In my opinion you need test it with iptables. Without it it make no sense. And we can't understand each other.

Comment: The regex matches all the samples of URLs you gave. (Otherwise let me know.) Now you need to use the regex in your iptables script/config. I do not know iptables, I do not have iptables. Somebody elses knowhow is needed for that. You might try to optimise the attractiveness of your question for iptables experts. I.e. think specially how you could use the tips from (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to target iptables gurus. E.g. how is it not working, though the regex matches appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But your suggestion doesn't work with iptables.

If you want help me please test it with iptables because you probably doesn't understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The line that includes the URL in the packet has not only the URL but also some extra keywords around it.

If you want to block "http://stackoverflow.com" **only**, then you should specify the URL like this:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "/\/ .+Host: stackoverflow.com/si" --algo regex -j DROP
```

or if you want to block "http://stackoverflow.com/questions" **only**, then you should specify the URL like this:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "/\/questions .+Host: stackoverflow.com/si" --algo regex -j DROP
```